# Why did Mumei "need to go to the toilet"?

Tags: koutetsujou-no-kabaneri

In episode 10 of Kabaneri, Biba (aka. the Liberator) visits the local lord. He takes his Kabaneri with him, including Mumei.

As soon as they arrive, Mumei claims she needs to go to the toilet, then uses that excuse to run all the way back to the station's gates and open them.

What I didn't understand was why Mumei needed to accompany Biba in the first place. Since opening the gates was part of a grander plan devised by Biba himself, wouldn't it have been simpler to just leave Mumei behind?

Even from a purely political point of view, there doesn't seem to be any reason for Mumei to act. Unlike Biba, she's not a particularly important (political) figure; she wasn't born in a particularly rich or notable family, and although she calls Biba "brother", the two of them aren't officially related. Her absence would likely have gone unnoticed by the lord and his retainers. And even if her absence had drawn attention...

> all of the witnesses would've been either murdered or kidnapped by Biba.

---

What was the point of taking Mumei along, then have her make up an excuse to run all the way back to the gates, instead of leaving her behind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it would be weird if she separated from Biba at any other point. They were closely followed and in open while going in. So it would raise an alarm if they tried something funny.

> And even if her absence had drawn attention... all of the witnesses would've been either murdered or kidnapped by Biba.

The point was not to draw attention until gates are open. If someone like Biba was just walking around it would definitely raise alarm. Someone like Mumei can easily stealth around and stun anyone who sees her. There is also added benefit of Biba staying with the "governor" distracting him.

And because only women and children were allowed to follow him inside (I assume because they believed women and children won't be a threat to soldiers), Mumei and the other woman were clear choices.